# performing submit(postback) and redirect with ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to use `submit` from my markup, to an ASP.net MVC action.

Then I want to redirect the request to another url.

Can I do so? Or MVC corresponding to ajax only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The post will happen if you're using an [Html.BeginForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505244.aspx) like so:

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm("HandleForm", "Home")) { %>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>
        <p>
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Field1) %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Field2) %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p> 
    </fieldset>
<% } %>
```

Then your controller action can perform a redirect:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult HandleForm(MyModel myModel)
{
    // Do whatever you need to here.

    return RedirectToAction("OtherAction", myModel);
}

public ActionResult OtherAction(MyModel myModel)
{
    return View(myModel);    
}
```

**EDIT:**: The above example will now bind with the following model and can be passed between actions:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If the submit includes many fields. Is there any input object?

Comment: I modified my answer to show how to pass input values back to the controller action.

Answer (score 1):

The code below demonstrates how to redirect a user to another action after they've submitted a form.

If you would like to preserve any of the submitted data for use in the action method you're redirecting to, you need to store it in the `TempData` object.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Get the e-mail address previously submitted by the user if it
        // exists, or use an empty string if it doesn't
        return View(TempData["email"] ?? string.Empty);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string email)
    {
        // Store the e-mail address submitted by the form in TempData
        TempData["email"] = email;

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Your `Index` view would look something like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
{
    @* Will populate the textbox with the previously submitted value, if any *@
    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" value="@Model" />

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```